# Is there a way to extend the lines of context for comparing strings in Jest?

Tags: jestjs

I have a NodeJS test in Jest which compares very long strings with lots of lines. In my real example this results from pretty-printed JSON but the simple example below illustrates the problem:

```
describe('Stuff', () => {
  it('should make it clear where the diff is but does not', () => {
    const str1 = 'Hellox\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nworldx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\n'
    const str2 = 'Hellox\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\n123\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nworldx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\n'
    expect(str1).toEqual(str2)
  })
})
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
  ● Stuff › should make it clear where the diff is but does not

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 0

    @@ -2,11 +2,10 @@
      x
      x
      x
      x
      x
    - 123
      x
      x
      x
      x
      x
```

There's so many similar or identical lines either side of the diff that it's very difficult to figure out where the problem is. Is there a way I can control or expand the context or is it hard-coded as a 5-before, 5-after rule?

Answer (score 1):

Not cleanly. There are options in jest-diff to set this:

https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/main/packages/jest-diff#options

However, at the time of writing, these are not passed through from the jest config - there's an open feature request for that:

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12576

Hence, there's no clean way to configure this. It is possible to simply edit the value in `node_modules/jest-diff/build/normalizeDiffOptions.js` which works but is nasty for obvious reasons.